# Dynamically update install4j screen content

Tags: install4j

We have a screen which displays only if we detect a problem with the environment. The screen has a button which retries the environment check. Each time the user retries the error can change and so I'd like to update my Multi-line HTML label accordingly. The content of the label needs to contain information produced during the environment check so even if we get the same type of error twice we may need a different message.

Is there a way to dynamically update the content of a screen? In other answers I've seen that it's usually recommended to set the content of the screen to a variable, and then updating the variable, but since I'm not moving between screens I don't believe the content will be updated. I've seen that calling `context.gotoScreen(currentScreen)` will refresh the content, but I'm worries this is not standard, and may change in the future in a way that if the provided screen is the current screen, nothing happens.

So the question is, what's the best approach to dynamically update the content of a screen based on user interaction without moving between screens.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time a form screen is shown, all form components will be reinitialized. For a multi-line HTML label component, this means that the label text will be refreshed.

To update all components from within the screen, call

```
formEnvironment.reinitializeFormComponents();
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo! I think that should work.

The title of the screen won't update though, right?

Comment: Not with the above call, but when the screen is activated, the title will be updated, so you can use an installer variable in the title to change it.

Comment: Yeah but I can't update it as a result of clicking on the button on the screen, right?